# GWT Designer deployment error

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

I am trying to deploy my first GWT application, but I am getting the error below.
I am using jre6, GWT Designer (with GWT DSK 2.5.0), and I have already deleted the gwt-unitCache folder as suggested here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/e3DoVrI6V70

```
Designer error occurred. 
Select Details >> for more information. 
See the Error Log for more information.
Reason: Parse error or internal Designer error.
Plug-in Provider: Google
Plug-in Name: 
Plug-in ID: org.eclipse

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/launching/IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction.getGWTProjectClasspath(DeployModuleAction.java:364)
at 
com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction.createBuildScript(DeployModuleAction.java:150) 
at
com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction.access$1(DeployModuleAction.java:131)
at
com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction$1.run(DeployModuleAction.java:103)
at
org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

Full stack trace (to see full context):
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction$1.run(DeployModuleAction.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/launching/IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction.getGWTProjectClasspath(DeployModuleAction.java:364)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction.createBuildScript(DeployModuleAction.java:150)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction.access$1(DeployModuleAction.java:131)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.actions.deploy.DeployModuleAction$1.run(DeployModuleAction.java:103)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I'm using Juno. I created an Ant build.xml file as a workaround and it's working OK.